# Angular, RxJS - How to cancel previous requests using switchMap?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I was trying to figure out that for a long time by myself but I stuck.

My case: I have a table with data, when user enters the page the request goes to REST API. Above the table there is a form that specify/filters results of the table. When user clicks a button, new request with query parameters goes to a service.

I'm trying to find a way to stop a previous request when user clicked a button, to search a table with specific parameters

Here is what I have done so far [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-86z7jg?file=src/app/app.component.ts). Maybe my approach is wrong and someone could show me how to write it better, or maybe there are just few thing to correct.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Please provide your code and specifically what isn't working about.  It's nice that you provided a stackblitz, but it isn't obvious what your issue is.

Comment: `switchMap()` doesn't "cancel" a previous http request, but rather will stop listening to responses from previous requests and only listen to responses from the newest request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **takeUntil** operator inside your **pipe**, and pass a **subject** to it, and everytime you apply a new filter you can emit something to that subject to unsubscribe from the previous subscription and subscribe again! let me give you an example on how to use this operator:

**regardless if your code was working or not!! I added just the part on how to use the takeUntil operator!**

```
...
 unsubscribe = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor(private _service: ServiceConnectService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.clickStream
      .pipe(
        map(() => console.log(1)),
        switchMap(() => {
          return this.getMethodServicesInstances();
        }),
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe) // this will be executed once you call next with a value!! and the subscription will be stopped!
      )
      .subscribe(results => {
        console.log(2);
      });
  }

  applyFilter(){
    this.unsubscribe.next(true);
    /*
      you can then rerun the subscription and reset the unsubscribe subject state to null!
     */
  }
...
```